# Div elements inside Pre elements add undesirable whitespace above and below line

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```css
pre {}

div.uncovered {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Line numbering test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
<div class="uncovered"><code>def f(a, b):</code></div>
<div><code>    return a+b</code></div>
    </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I need to have `div` elements because I would like the background color to span the width of my entire browser window. However, the `div` element also adds whitespace between the `code` elements, which I *do not want*. I tried adjusting the margins and padding of the `div` element in my CSS to 0, but this had no effect. I also tried playing around with the `white-space` property of the `div`, some of the options (like `nowrap`) would remove the whitespace, but would also remove the spaces before my `return` statement, which is also not desirable.

I don't understand why `div` is adding this whitespace. `Div` is a block element and following the box model, all whitespace should be accounted for by either the margin or padding. Why is this happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre can contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) i.e. not divs - you need to put the pre inside the divs

You need to reset all the elements (you can limit yourself to pre, code and div if needed

Here the `<pre>` is enough so we can remove the `<code>`

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0;}
div.uncovered {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Line numbering test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="uncovered"><pre>def f(a, b):</pre></div>
<div><pre>    return a+b</pre></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Perhaps better alternative

We can have the code tag AND assign white-space: pre to it. Then we have semantic and visual consistency

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0;}
code { display:block; white-space: pre;}
code.uncovered {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<code class="uncovered">def f(a, b):</code>
<code>    if a &lt; b:
        return a+b
    else:    
        return b-a</code>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Is there any real point still having the `<code>` tag?

Comment: @user32882 `code`  tags are inline, they do not affect line breaks etc.

Comment: @user32882 We can have the code tag AND assign white-space: pre to it. Then we have semantic and visual consistency

Comment: I tried the html without the `code` tag and it looks exactly the same....

Comment: Many many ways to skin a cat - I just took your code

Comment: I understand... It might be the subject of a future question. Thanks

Comment: @user32882 see update. No <code> in the first, no <div> and <pre> in the second

Answer (score 0):

Please do not put nothing inside a CSS selector properties, e.g.:

```
pre {}
```

Next, negative padding values will not work, but margins will:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: -20px; /* Will not work */
  margin: -20px;
  font-size: 8px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">You may not be able to see this box</div>
```

Finally, you can clean and fix the code.

```css
div.uncovered {
  background-color: red;
}
code {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Line numbering test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <pre>
    <div class="uncovered"><code>def f(a, b):</code></div>
    <code>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;return a+b</code>
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

In HTML avoid using more than one space because HTML will ignore the rest. I replaced   (whitespace),
 with the unicode alternative `&nbsp;`.

Comment: You still have a large gap from div to code tag on next line

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply `display: block;` + `white-space: pre;` and only use the `<code>` tag to achieve a similar result:

```css
code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  /* for more space between lines  */
  /* margin-bottom: 10px;  */
}

code.uncovered {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <code class="uncovered">def f(a, b):</code>
  <code>    if a > b:</code>
  <code>        return a - b</code>
  <code>    else:</code>
  <code>        return a + b</code>
  
</body>
</html>
```